# Node.js bash: /usr/local/bin/node: Permission denied

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js

I'm installing Node.js on Ubuntu machine. I followed official instructions:

```
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

So, I got node binary in `/usr/local/bin/node` and all dependencies. But when I run it from command line I get permission error:

```
> node
bash: /usr/local/bin/node: Permission denied
```

How can I fix it? How can I run it under my account? `sudo node` doesn't work too.

Comment: what does `ls -l /usr/local/bin/node` output?

Comment: `-rwxr-x--- 1 root root 11105680 Dec 13 09:46 /usr/local/bin/node`. Oh, I sees, `chown`? This worked! @rossipedia put it in the answer, I'll mark it as resolved. Thank you!

Comment: I wouldn't use `chown` to change permissions on that. The problem is that you only have +x permissions for root and root's group. Usually that should read `-rwxr-xr-x`, which gives everybody read and execute permissions. @hek2mgl's answer below is the correct one.

Comment: @demi Are you working on the `next generation google linux`? (your profile says that you are working there) :) At least good old `GNU\Linux` will work as I've showed in my answer

Comment: @hek2mgl yes, it's Goobuntu. But I really don't know what is so special about it:)

Comment: @demi (chuckle) :) ... but does my answer at least worked for you? it should. I did some research to find the proper quote from standard to prove my answer (I guess it should be in in LSB (linux standard base), but it showed to be require more effort as I can give on a friday evening.. maybe will add link tomorrow :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need read- and executable permissions for `others`. Issue:

```
sudo chmod +rx $(which node)
```

or

```
sudo chmod 755 $(which node)
```

However, normally `make install` should set that permissions. Looks like something in the `Makefile` is wrong.

Comment: Thx :) The whole GNU userland is fantastic! Can't stop loving it :)

Comment: I have `node` executable for the user (see comment under answer about `ls -l`). For me, `chown` worked (it was `root root` as you can see). `chmod` didn't help.

Comment: Binaries (or scripts) located in `/usr/local/bin` are expected to be owned by root, group root and having permissions set to `755`. That's standard. I'm not sure what you are doing there.

Comment: Also I expect that `make install` will install to `/usr/bin` and not `/usr/local/bin`. Maybe you have an old node binary residing in `/usr/local/bin` which get's executed (or makes trouble) instead of the previously installed binary by make install (to `/usr/bin`) ?

Comment: I ran into this error after having run `+x`, turned out `others` didn't have read access and it needs both.  So `755` (or `+xr`) might be necessary if `+x` is insufficient.

Comment: @dimo414 Thanks. I've edited that. When posting the answer I assumed read permissions had been granted already.

Comment: In my case I knew node binarie path, so : sudo chmod +rx /apps/.../node-v4.2.3-linux-x64/bin/node works!! THanks hek2mgl

Answer (score 2):

For people with no knowledge of osx terminal, open it and use these commands:

```
su yourusername
su chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/node
sudo node install...
```

This will make the folder readable/writeable and the sudo before the node command will make it run under admin rights.

Comment: Worked for me with my custom node install in SAP Hybris. Thank you!

Comment: FYI "su chmod..." didn't work for me in my Mac - I had to do "sudo chmod..."